# Convert user.id to user.username in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am implementing the very cool third party package [Django-Simple-History](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) into a project. Per the documentation I'm using the middleware to store which user makes changes to an object. This makes it easy to iterate over in the template like:

```
{% for x in object.history.all %}
{{ x.history_date }}, {{ x.history_user_id }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

I am trying to use the available user.id to get the correlating user.username in the template. Any suggestions? (I'm still pretty new to Django/Python) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`history_user` holds the ForeignKey for the related user.

You can use: `{{ x.history_user.username }}`

Comment: thank you, I was looking at the DB columns and only saw the user.id being stored and got stuck there

Comment: @brandondavid Django (like others) does not store the serialized user object in the DB as FK, it stores the user id and uses that to retrieve the related user.

Comment: once again I learn the hard way that if I am jumping through hoops to make something in django work I'm probably doing it wrong. The answer was so simple. Thanks again!